# Angular model change isn't reflected to html select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have an html list with a form for defining filter values. In this form there is a select box:

```
<div style="...">
  <label for="lstCategory">Category:</label><br/>
  <select name="category" id="lstCategory" ng-model="category" ng-change="loadActivities()">
    <option value="0">default1</option>
    <option value="1">default2</option>
    <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.id }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

In my controller I bind the "categories" model to a REST resource:

```
.controller('AppointmentsHomeCtrl', [
...
function(
  ...
) {
  $scope.location = typeof $location.search().location != 'undefined' ?
    $location.search().location :
    '0';
  $scope.category = typeof $location.search().category != 'undefined' ?
    $location.search().category :
    '0';

  $scope.categories = CategoriesResource.query();
```

Now I want to preselect a value in this select box, depending on the dearch parameter "location" in my url, which is done by the `$scope.category = typeof $locati.......` part of the code.

My problem is, that this preselection isn't reflected to my HTML while the mnodel itself has the correct value.

I already tryed to set the value after the query to the resource is done by watching the resource or giving a callback function to the "query" method but this also isn't working.

Did I missed something here? What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Edit:

It seems to recognise the options since:

`$scope.category = "foo";` adds a pseudo option which gets selected.

But when I choose an existiong id, nothing happens at all:

`$scope.category = "3";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at controller you can try this method for preselect value

```
$scope.precategory = '0'; //just for example value
```

then on your html code make sure ng-model having different variable with ng-repeat like this one

```
<select name="category" id="lstCategory" ng-model="precategory " ng-change="loadActivities()">
<option value="0">default1</option>
<option value="1">default2</option>
<option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.id }}</option>
```

that method will help solve your problem, because i was getting same problem before :)

Comment: I tried to rename the model but it doesn't solved the problem.

Comment: if you rename the model you need add same name on the controller, but another trick and some it help is you can change value="{{ category.id }}" to ng-value="{{ category.id }}" this method usually i use when using text box

Comment: Yes, i also renamed it in the controller. With ng-model it doesn't recognises the values from the select box and it adds a new option: ```<option value="? string:3 ?">```. I also tried the int version of "3" with the same result.

Comment: can you print out what result of categories? because this error <option value="? string:3 ?"> happen when return from json is wrong too and have you try ng-selected="{{category.id==precategory}}" this method will select your option value :)

Comment: When I use "value" it recognises th options, since it isn't generating this pseudo option if I use a value which is in the options.

Comment: ```ng-selected="{{category.id==precategory}}"``` did the trick. But shouldn't be necessary in my oppinion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$scope.categories = CategoriesResource.query();` try:

```
CategoriesResource.query().then(function(result) {
    $scope.categories = result;
});
```

You may have to tweak it a bit if the result is not an array...

Comment: This produces an exception: ```Error: CategoriesResource.query(...).then is not a function```

Comment: I'm not sure what `CategoriesResource` is, but I guess it has a promise somewhere. You should add .then(...) to this promise... Try `CategoriesResource.query().$promise.then(...)`, or `console.log(CategoriesResource.query())` and check where the promise is...

Comment: Yes, I found the promise. It was .$promise but it didn't solved my problem.